# Why is my VHD actual/physical size bigger than the virtual size?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vhd

I have a Windows VM, It uses the VHD format as the hard drive and I set the VHD to dynamically allocated. Initially, I set the virtual size to 80GB, and then recently I changed my mind and resized it to 100GB using the Virtual Media Manager inside VirtualBox. The actual size after expanding it is around 180 GB, which doesn't make sense to me, the VM still has 12 GB free from the 100 GB virtual size of the VHD. Anyone knows why this happens and how to fix it?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9sEe.png) is what it looks like from Disk Management inside the VM.

Comment: How exactly did you resize the virtual disk? Also check Virtual Media Manager, does it show anything unusual about the virtual disk?

Comment: Oh yes, and maybe also provide a screenshot of Disk Management inside the VM.

Comment: @DanielB updated the question for the answer :)

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Okay, the screenshot confirms the VM really just sees a 100 GB disk. Did you check Virtual Media Manager yet? Does it show anything of note?

Answer (score -2):

It seems like virtualbox has created a snapshot of your old disk.

So you now have inside the one VHD file the old disk at 80 GB *and*
the new disk at 100 GB, which makes up 180 GB in all!

Verify this by following the "Delete a snapshot" section in the
[Oracle VM VirtualBox User Manual for Release 6.0 - Snapshots](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/snapshots.html).

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think so, I checked the list of snapshots on the VM, and it has none, only "Current State". Really weird, indeed.

Comment: Indeed. The 180 GB figure is too neat to be ignored.